# Confused by Lisp list comparison

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Below I'm having a with my Lisp program with a comparison between a list and a list. One is generated from user input and one is part of table that is pre-generated. I test the function with set input separately; there, `(isValidMove '(0 0))` returns `T,` yet when build a list for comparisons using *query-io* I get false. Comparison, in any language, has always given me trouble because of how many different things are identical to me but apparently vastly different to the computer; I assume that's the same problem I'm having here. (By the way, I'm including only a part of a larger program).

```
;Local Variables (program wide)
;Board values stores x/o and defaults to " "
(setf boardValues (make-array '(3 3)
    :initial-element " ")
);end boardValues

;List of all valid moves remaining 
(setf validMoves (list 
    (list 0 0) (list 0 1) (list 0 2) 
    (list 1 0) (list 1 1) (list 1 2) 
    (list 2 0) (list 2 1) (list 2 2)))

;Functions

;Function call the will prompt the user for input, if the move is
;not vaild, repromts for a move
(defun getUserMove ()

    (let ((move (read-line *query-io*)))
    (if (isValidMove move)
        (progn
            (setf (aref validMoves (car move) (cdr move)) 'x)
            (remove move validMoves))
            (getUserMove)))
);end getUserMove

;Function call that process the move, returns T if move is valid
;and F if move is invalid

(defun isValidMove (move)
    (dolist (m validMoves) 
    (if (equalp m move)
        (return T)))
) ;end isValidMove
```

Comment: Read-line returns a string. It looks like you are comparing that to numbers without converting it first.

Comment: A stylistic point: don't leave trailing parens on their own line please.  Also the comments saying where the ends of expressions are is not necessary. Indentation and paren matching show the expressions.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I actually find that harder to read, personally, but I'll adjust to the style of Lisp.

Comment: More nitpicks: "is-valid-move" is preferred to "isValidMove". Also, you say that *"comparison, in any language, has always given me trouble because of how many different things are identical to me but apparently vastly different to the computer"*. There are many useful ways to define equality. The only way to know for sure what a specific operator does is to refer to the documentation.

Comment: Without proper formatting and indenting, writing software will be much harder than it should be. Improve the layout of the code!

Comment: AREF is an operator for arrays, not lists.

Comment: You can always try to debug your code using tools like TRACE, STEP, DESCRIBE, INSPECT, BREAK, the debugger, ... even (PRINT ...) may help.

Comment: Note also that it's useful to show a test case and an error message. Once you have that, you are also half on the way to solve the problem yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the code fixing problems:

```
(setf boardValues (make-array '(3 3)
    :initial-element " ")
)
```

Do not use `SETF` to declare global variables. Use `DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER`. Global variables are *special*: to indicate this, use "ear-muffs". Also, you don't need comments in Common Lisp telling what a variable or a function is for: use doc-strings when defining them:

```
(defvar *board-values* (make-array '(3 3) :initial-element " ")
  "Board values stores x/o and defaults to \" \"")
```

Also, use Common Lisp naming conventions (no camel case, use `-` to separate words; IMHO Lisp's convention is way more readable).

The same issue with `VALIDMOVES`. Replace your definition with:

```
(defvar *valid-moves*
  (list '(0 0) '(0 1) '(0 2) 
        '(1 0) '(1 1) '(1 2) 
        '(2 0) '(2 1) '(2 2))
  "List of all valid moves remaining ")
```

Now, the change in the function is more involved:

```
(defun get-user-move ()
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (let ((move (read-from-string (read-line *query-io*))))
      (when (valid-move-p move)
        (setf (aref *board-values* (car move) (cadr move)) 'x)
        (setf *valid-moves* (remove move *valid-moves* :test #'equalp))
        (get-user-move)))))
```

Let's look at it line-by-line:

1. Use CL name convention
2. We will be reading from the string. CL has *reader macros*, powerful but dangerous things. By setting `*READ-EVAL*` to `NIL` we suppress the evaluation that can happen at read-time.
3. Read user input into variable `MOVE`: `READ-LINE` will take user input and return a string of the input, `READ-FROM-STRING` will convert the string into Lisp-data. So if user inputs "(1 2)", `MOVE` will contain the list `(1 2)`.
4. We perform multiple actions on the valid move and do nothing if it isn't valid. Better use `WHEN` instead of `IF` in this case: won't need `PORGN` and show more precisely what we are doing compared to `IF`. It is more idiomatic in CL to name the predicate with `-P` ending instead of having `IS` in front, thus `ISVALIDMOVE` is renamed to `VALID-MOVE-P`.
5. Here I assume the original program had an error: you were calling `AREF` on `VALIDMOVES` which is not an array. I assume you wanted to change the state of the board. Notice that coordinates are taken using `CAR` and `CADR` of the `MOVE`: `MOVE` is the list not just a pair, in effect it has a form `(CONS X (CONS Y NIL))`. So, to get `Y` need to take `(CAR (CDR MOVE))` or `(CADR MOVE)` or `(SECOND MOVE)`; `(CDR MOVE)` will return `(Y)` - not a valid index for an array.
6. `REMOVE` does not affect original sequence! Even if you use destructive `DELETE` you shouldn't rely on it changing the original sequence, but use the returned value. Thus, need to re-assign `*VALID-MOVES*` value after removing the move. Also, need to supply a different equality test for `REMOVE` since `(EQL (LIST 1 2) (LIST 1 2))` is `NIL`.
7. Recursively call itself. Perhaps, more idiomatic CL code would use `LOOP`, but there is nothing wrong with recursion here.

NB: I have changed the semantic of a function a bit: it returns on an invalid move. Otherwise, the user has to interrupt the evaluation to stop. Even better would be to have a special input for exit (symbol `QUIT` or `Q`?) and re-prompt for input in case of invalid move.

Finally, function `VALID-MOVE-P` is quite trivial in CL:

```
(defun valid-move-p (move)
  (member move *valid-moves* :test #'equalp))
```

Instead of manually walking through the list, can use primitive (in a sense "provided by CL standard") function `MEMBER`.

Now it works:

```
CL-USER> (get-user-move)
(0 1)
(0 2)
(10 20)
NIL
CL-USER> *board-values*
#2A((" " X X) (" " " " " ") (" " " " " "))
CL-USER> *valid-moves*
((0 0) (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (2 0) (2 1) (2 2))
```

PS. The code is still far from the ideal but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In `GETUSERMOVE` you bind `MOVE` to be the result of evaluating `READ-LINE`. `READ-LINE` returns a *string* not a *list*. (ref: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm)

Thus `ISVALIDMOVE` can never evaluate to `T` given that a string will never be `EQUALP` to a list.

To transform your string into a list you will need to call `EVAL`. But be cautious about using `EVAL` on user inputted data!

Comment: You do not need to use `eval`, `read` suffices.  You do not even need that, you can also use `split-sequence` and `parse-integer`.